# replacing characters in arraylist

Tags: java, string, arraylist, replace, replaceall

I am working with the replace method for strings. I have an array list of strings and am trying to allow the user to select a letter to remove from the array and a letter to replace it with. When I execute the program and after the user selects the character to replace, the array stays the same.

Could someone explain why this is happening?

My array list is called "strings". The portion of my code dealing with the replace function is below:

```
public void letter () {

            int b;

            Scanner replaceLetter = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println ("What letter would you like to remove?");
            String badLetter = replaceLetter.next();
            System.out.println ("What letter would you like to add?");
            String newLetter = replaceLetter.next();
            for (b=0; b<strings.size(); b++) {
                    String replaceLetters  = strings.get(b);
                    replaceLetters = replaceLetters.replaceAll(badLetter,newLetter);

            }
            System.out.print(strings);

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

All you're doing is updating the reference to `replaceLetters`, *not* replacing the string that is at the specified index in your array `strings`.  You should add the line:

```
strings.set(b, replaceLetters);
```

to the end of your for loop:

```
 for (b=0; b<strings.size(); b++) {
   String replaceLetters  = strings.get(b);
   replaceLetters = replaceLetters.replaceAll(badLetter,newLetter);
   strings.set(b, replaceLetters);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put it back in the ArrayList again. String is immutable in java.

set it to existing position.

```
for (b=0; b<strings.size(); b++) {
   String replaceLetters  = strings.get(b);
   replaceLetters = replaceLetters.replaceAll(badLetter,newLetter);
   strings.set(b, replaceLetters);
 }
```

Comment: +1 right and code need to add `Strings.set(b,replaceLetters)`

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder yes. Edited as so.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
replaceLetters = replaceLetters.replaceAll(badLetter,newLetter);
```

only changes the value of the `replaceLetters` variable.  It doesn't put it back in the array.  For that, you need the `set` method of the `ArrayList` class.  Add this line immediately below that one.

```
strings.set(b, replaceLetters);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `replaceAll` call returns an entirely new String instance which you're not inserting, or replacing, into your array.

Answer (score 0):

```
replaceLetters = replaceLetters.replaceAll(badLetter,newLetter);
```

This will return a new String without updating it in the arraylist so you should put it again in the array list

```
strings.set(b, replaceLetters);
```